# Manager does not develop employees

Tags: management, communication, career-development, manager

I'm working as an offshore Senior ERP Developer with a BPO Company for over a year now and my Manager and peers are working in the United States.
I've been successfully been taking on large projects and, in my opinion, I was able to do a lot for the company in a year

From my past working experience, there has always been an annual performance appraisal and I wanted to know how I am doing as an Employee.
(Please note that the company didn't provide me with an Orientation).
And based on our ERP system (which i have access to), i am scheduled to have an appraisal.
With that, I reached out to my Manager via Email (Titled "Career Progression for ____ " and asked:

> Hi Manager,
>
> I would want to ask if you would have time later in the day to discuss my career with Company X.
>
> I would just want to know what are the current plans for me,  which areas I excel and which ones can develop more,
>
> and how I can grow technically and professionally with Company X. Please let me know your availability to discuss. Thank you.

After some hours, still got no response so I reached out to him over Skype and we finally talked about it.
Basically the gist was:

> Me:  Recently celebrated my 1st year with Company X and I just wanted to thank you for the challenges, opportunities, and learnings you’ve provided me.
>
> Me:  What are Management’s plans for me, in terms of opportunity, career advancement and professional development?
>
> MGR: Foreseeing you to be the Subject Matter Expert in another year or two. When the opportunity comes, will make mention of your work to Management when asked.
>
> Me:  When will we have Annual Performance Appraisals?
>
> MGR: Company X used to have annual appraisals but now appraisals are a case-to-case basis.
>
> Me:  Would it be possible for me to request for formal Trainings / Certifications to improve my technical skill?
>
> MGR: it is unclear if Company X sponsors formal trainings. Send a list of preferred training courses and would check with management.

P.S. I also sent this discussion over an email as to have documentation.

It seems to me my manager doesn't have any plans to develop my skills and only provided open-ended possibilities and has no formal plans for me.
I already sent him a list of formal trainings months back but he keeps on saying he's going to check with Management/HR.

What can I possibly do to get an appraisal or get support for a formal training?

Some context, my manager shares the same characteristics as the manager in this Question ([How to proceed when remote boss doesn't answer emails?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21981/how-to-proceed-when-remote-boss-doesnt-answer-emails)), Among others.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by exposure? @RichardU

Comment: To sum up:  your manager is not supporting your requests that the company spend money to train you, is not responsive to your requests for promotion, and you think he will get angry with you for being persistent.  Sounds like you have your answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I possibly do to get an appraisal or get support for a formal
>   training?

In the case of formal training, all you can do is keep asking, via email for the training you need.  Be sure to include the *cost*, location of said training, **and the benefits to him and your company**.

In terms of the appraisal, that should happen on a yearly basis in most cases.  Again, make the request for this in email, but ask for a date.  This is a bit different in that your anniversary date is known.  ( *so a review date should be able to be set* )  You can try asking for this face to face or via Skype if that would be better for you.  ( you know your boss, I don't )

It does sound a bit like you may not be able to get the feedback and growth that you need on this job, so the ultimate answer may be, *to quote Captain Obvious*, to get another job.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, knowing my boss, I think he'll get angry when i follow up on an appraisal, especially via email. Thinking of other ways to bring this up with him.

Comment: How about trying face to face?  If that doesn't work, again not sure what you can do here.

Comment: i cannot have face to face meetings with him as he's on another continent. We only communicate via Skype. :(

Comment: Ok, then Skype.  Answer updated.