# My former Manager Isn't giving an Endorsement to my new Manager

Tags: management, salary, manager, performance-reviews, appraisal

Two months ago ("January"), I asked my manager regarding my development to which was left with open-ended answers (Read: [Manager does not develop employees](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/100092/manager-does-not-develop-employees)).
Coincidentally, it was announced that all employees from the Offshore Team, including me, will be moved to a new "Independent" organization ("Org X"), effective next month ("February").

Upon learning this, I immediately emailed my Onshore Manager ("MM"), asking for a salary and/or performance appraisal.
After numerous follow-ups, my Manager finally responded a month later ("March"):

> "Since you're already under Org X, they will be the one to give you your appraisal."

But since the new Director ("CC") in Org X is a new employee and doesn't really know who I am and what I do / have done, I asked MM for an endorsement to him instead, to which he responded:

> "I should not give them an endorsement, CC should ask an endorsement from me."

Isn't it normal practice to provide an endorsement to my new Manager from my old Manager? It seems to me its just an excuse to give an endorsement. What can i do to get an appraisal?

Just some notes to consider:

- The two Managers MM and CC aren't communicating for some reason.
- CC and MM are situated in different regions in the world (CC is in the same country as I am).

Comment: You were moved to Org-X "_effective August 2017_" and CC still "_doesn't really know who you are and what you do / have done_"?

Comment: @SandraK, edited for clarity. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you report to "CC", the right thing to do would be to contact him and ask for your performance review. If he is now your manager, it is part of his job to get to know you and what it is that you do. If he is very new, he may still be getting settled in and may not be able to do it immediately, but should be able to give you an estimate of when it would be suitable.

If "CC" needs information from your previous managers or coworkers to complete a performance review, he will reach out to them and ask you directly. Your old managers have changed responsibilities and have new staff and tasks to worry about now. If their input is needed, it will be asked for by the person who would need it.

I only see two strange things. First, how long it took your original manager "MM" to respond to a question about an evaluation. It seems like it was nearly a month. That's a very long time. However, he may have known about the reorganization and (either of his choosing or by instruction) decided to defer your request until a later date. Second, that your organization does not have regularly scheduled times for performance reviews and appraisals. In my experiences, many places do it on a regular schedule (my current company does it in the June/July timeframe, my last company did it in November/December/January).

Comment: Regarding the regular performance reviews, I find that very strange as well, and a bit unfair to be honest.