# How to handle authority who doesn't let you grow because of insecurity?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues

Long Version

I work in Indian IT industry here we have off-shore [India] and on-shore [Abroad] culture for companies from abroad. On shore [Abroad] people have the most influence and they are key decision makers.

I joined my company as trainee and got project to work on. I worked very well and performed out of expectations. For last 2 years my potential was limited to off shore people or my colleagues. All going good.

Then after some time when my current authority didn't had any interest to work in project. There was no one to stop me from anything. I was directly dealing with clients in many cases providing solutions and solving issues. No one had any issues with this.

This quickly built my repo with clients/on-shore colleagues and for them I became key resource of project.

Later I found myself new opportunity and resigned. But so many efforts were taken for me to retain that I have been offered employment outside of my country on 8x pay of current salary.

I retained and due to this corona situation I am still off shore.

But this exposed my full potential to colleagues who were in lead position above me in off shore. They understood that I am doing work of solution architect also and my role is only developer. This made them feel insecure. Even though they had no interest before to work in this project. Suddenly started to pull me down in various things like as I am developer I don't have authority over things. They are not letting me deal with clients or do the solutioning. All I do is just code. Even my new ideas are not appreciated anymore.

I don't know how to deal with these colleague who is my authority but not letting me grow even if I am capable.

Currently as I understand they want to cherry pick the credit of project and then just leave. But at the same time my name is not coming anywhere. Even though I am working as key resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manager does not develop employees](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/100092/manager-does-not-develop-employees)

Comment: `because of insecurity` - Unless this person has said to you "I can't let you grow because I'm insecure." then you can't know the genesis of the behavior and it's presumptuous to assume a reason.

Comment: This question makes a needless assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons people do things is not in your control.  You will never be able to manage multiple people when you think you know their motivations. And it really doesn't matter.  What you need to focus on is how do you like your work relative to what you are paid, and how does your current job help you fulfill your career goals.

If how **you** feel about your job isn't enough for you to stay, then you need to find other work.  Either that, or spend energy trying to manage up.  This would probably start with talking to the people who you think are wronging you.  Understand that you may need an exit strategy if you choose to challenge you boss' decisions.