# Working on Internal Project with no expectations from Manager

Tags: communication, management, manager, offices

I have been working on an Internal Project for 6 months now. There is no status call, no Client pitching for this project, even no updates on the presentation which they show to Client (there is a wrong information about database used).

My manager doesn't responds to my emails (he is remote), I keep on sending updates, talking to mid level manager, who is also working in another project and handles this one casually.

What should be my approach to convey that I want to work in a this project, specially this way, I do not want to be considered as "NO ONE". I already have sent emails describing what I feel, as expected got unanswered.
No doubt I keep myself busy with challenges and competition online and answering questions on portals.

Comment: Hi, "Should I switch", "Should I wait at least one year" aren't really the sort of thing we answer here; they're personal decisions that are both something you've got to figure out for yourself based on your personal situation, and also something not likely to help anyone.  If you'd like advice, you should rephrase the question in a slightly more general manner; asking how you can get more helpful feedback, for example, or how you can ensure your career growth, may be more useful and more answerable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to proceed when remote boss doesn't answer emails?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21981/how-to-proceed-when-remote-boss-doesnt-answer-emails)

Comment: Could you make your question a little bit more specific ? It feels more like you're describing your situation and waiting for advice than really trying to solve a specific problem: What do you want to do (get more work, change project, get recognition for your work ...) ? What is the most important thing that bothers you ? (Your manager not responding to your mails, no Client pitching on your project , etc.) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I keep myself busy with challenges and competition online and answering questions on portals

I assume your employer doesn't pay your salary to have you do this kind of stuff.

First you can try setting up a meeting with your manager to discuss about your performance so far, and see how your work is seen in the company. There you can also address the lack of communication and challenge you feel.
At least you should be able to tell if the lack of interaction with the manager is due to the manager's style or to a genuine lack of interest in the project itself.

Then, if you want to grow further, and this project doesn't seem to fit your ambition and skills, you can consider switching to another job, either in the same company or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> My manager doesn't responds to my emails (he is remote), I keep on sending updates, talking to mid level manager, who is also working in another project and handles this one casually.

If your manager isn't responding to your emails, try getting in touch some other way (instant messenger, Skype, Phone, etc.) and try to stress the urgency of the matter.

If you still can't get through to him at all, you have no work to do, and you're talking to a mid level manager instead (who I assume is above your manager), then eventually you'll get to the point where you'll have to just ask him about your (direct) manager's seeming absence:

> Hi Alice,
>
> I've tried to get a status update on project Y from Bob, but haven't heard from him in the last 3 weeks. He's not answering his phone, and isn't replying to emails or on Skype. I urgently need to know the status of `x`, `y` and `z` as it's impossible for me to proceed without this information. Could you advise on how I should proceed?
>
> Thanks,
>
> Iti