# Urge someone in the kindest way possible

Tags: relationships

I'm asking to one of my collegue to send me a file (that He should have already sent me).
I've already asked him about this file a couple of weeks ago with something like this:

> Have you got any news about this topic?

But unfortunately I haven't seen this file yet

In the end I must again ask (in the most polite way possible) to send me that file as soon as possible.

Comment: Is politeness more important than getting the file?  Not that you should be impolite, but I'm trying to gauge the importance of the politeness to the importance of getting the file.

Comment: yes it is very important, because I am asking for the file to a superior of my company but from another branch.  Let's say he is a better position than me but He has no power on me.

Comment: Have you tried calling or communicating with company chat with this person?

Comment: I get in touch with this guy **only** by email, once every 3/4 months or for some specific project

Comment: "any update?" is never useful. see https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/21987/102

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sf02 has a good answer, but I would modify the actual request:

> Hello X.  I need file (include filename) as soon as possible so I can (do something with it, hopefully something that X thinks is important too).  If it's not processed by (date), then (these are the consequences). If you still need something from me first, please let me know, and I will take care of that right away. Thank you.

Then, if you get no response, go to your boss and ask how to proceed.  Unless you get a response in the next day or two, at least connect with your boss and let them know there is a delay.  It's always better to loop the boss in before something is late.

Comment: I really like your aproach and adding a final date is a touch of class and professionalism! TY

Answer (score 2):

You have already sent a reminder with no response.  I would reply to your last reminder and CC your boss.  You can politely ask again for the status of your request with something like:

> Hello X, just following up on this request.  Let me know if you need any additional information.  Thanks.

If after this you still do not hear back from this colleague then it is time to try calling or using whatever chat software your company uses to communicate with this person.

If you are worried about somehow offending this colleague by directly trying to communicate with them then you should speak to your boss.  Remind your boss that this person has not delivered the file (refer him to the email thread that you CCed him ) and ask him how he wants you to proceed.

Comment: Yes, if something is holding your work back, you need to speak to your boss (or project manager, etc), and they may be able to get a better response (and if they know this other figure, they may have a better idea how to approach). It's possible your boss will tell you to email them again, and if that happens, send a brief, polite email and if there's no response in a few days, tell your boss again.