# Manager does not reply to my message for days. What should I do if he ignores my follow-up message?

Tags: communication, manager, employer-relations

My message is regarding a time-sensitive issue. It's not a complicated question though, as it just requires a yes or no answer.

He read my message on the chat program we use, but he did not make a reply. I sent a follow-up message a few days later, but I'm worried about what to do if he doesn't respond to this follow-up message either. We all work from home, so it's impossible for me to talk with him in person. To set up a meeting with him, I have to message him, which wouldn't work because he's not replying in the first place. Calling him out of the blue may not be appropriate. I'm going to assume his answer is a "no" if he continues not replying to my message, but I don't know if this would be a safe assumption to make.

What would be an appropriate action to take in this situation?

Comment: Does he have a work phone (Cell Phone) assigned to him ? If yes, can you call him and leave a message because this is a work-related issue ? In addition, you can also send him a text message to that phone number.  BTW, have you sent him an email to his work email address ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to proceed when remote boss doesn't answer emails?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21981/how-to-proceed-when-remote-boss-doesnt-answer-emails)

Comment: _"Calling him out of the blue may not be appropriate."_ Why wouldn't it be appropriate? If something is time-sensitive, then resorting to a synchronous communication channel like phone if you don't get a response otherwise is probably your only remaining option.

Comment: If the manager has specifically said not to call him, then calling may be inappropriate. But otherwise it seems fine (I assume you know the manager's approximate working hours.)

Answer (score 23):

Phrase your emails in a way that puts the onus on him to respond. So instead of asking:

> We have a problem. Should I do FOO or BAR?

Send an email saying something like:

> We have a problem. I'm going to do FOO this afternoon in order to solve it, but if you'd prefer me to do BAR then please let me know.

And if he doesn't respond, then you can do FOO rather than waiting and hoping that he'll get back to you.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly; good managers will appreciate this approach because if they approve of your solution you've freed them to continue working on other tasks *and* indicated prioritization. That said, in a message like this I would consider adding specifics around the time you're doing FOO ("if you'd prefer BAR please respond by 2:00pm" - this can also be the email subject to make the deadline visible) and a synopsis of why you think FOO should be chosen over BAR so a manager can be informed as to how you came to your conclusion.

Comment: Leaves the ball in their court - especially when they come back after…

Answer (score 4):

Trust me – **managers are extremely busy.**  Just ask again.  Follow-up as seems appropriate.  Especially, don't "over-think" the fact that you maybe didn't get an answer as quickly as you expected.  ("You really have **no** idea, until you've actually held that job title!")

Comment: Agreed, and use the damn phone already.

Comment: Also state when the deadline is when emailing and following up; the manager may not appreciate it's urgent and might think they can deal with it when they see you next.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not a complicated question though, as it just requires a yes or no answer.

Just because the answer can be a simple yes/no, it doesn't mean the decision is necessarily a simple one. He may need to take time to consider the options, or he may need to check with someone else.

> He read my message on the chat program we use, but he did not make a reply. I sent a follow-up message a few days later, but I'm worried about what to do if he doesn't respond to this follow-up message either. We all work from home, so it's impossible for me to talk with him in person.

As your line manager his job is to guide your work. He's not doing that if you have no regular lines of communication. Your boss should be managing those lines of communication, but if he's not you should suggest to him what form this could take.

My team have a daily "Standup" meeting early in the day where we give a quick summary of what we've done, what we're planning to do and anything that is blocking us. This is standard practise in our industry (software development). The meeting is quick, so you don't necessarily do into the details of the blockers, but you do agree what the next step to unblock the problem is and who will take that action. Because the meetings are daily there is a regular opportunity to update on progress being made or deadlines getting tighter.

Another common practise is to have a scheduled 1:1 meeting with your manager, maybe once per week. Working remotely that would take the form of a voice or video call. Because it's a conversation between two people your manager has to answer the questions you ask them. It might not be the immediate yes/no answer you're hoping for, but they can tell you what their next step will be (e.g. checking with someone else, or even just spending some time thinking about it). If that's going to cause problems you've got an immediate opportunity to let them know - e.g. if there's a deadline that has to be met.

Another answer mentioned that managers are extremely busy. That's often true, but as with any role they need to balance their responsibilities and let their manager know if they have too much work for one person to manage. One of their responsibilities is to line manage you, and they need to find time to do that. Middle managers often have packed calendars, so you can help them to dedicate time to you by making sure that you've got a scheduled slot in that calendar.

Answer (score -6):

> "What should I do if my manager ignores my messages about a time
> sensitive matter?"

Move on. Don't make assumptions. The responsibility is theirs, not yours.

Comment: This answer needs more clarification. By "Move on." do you mean find another job or do you mean "act as if the manager is approving of everything you do"? Then, you say "Don't make assumptions." which negates the move on.

Comment: I don't think the edit here is appropriate. While the answer definitely is unclear, going from "Move on"  to "move on to another job" seems way to much. There is no indication in this answer at all to assume @joeqwerty meant to say this.