# How to proceed when a manager doesn't answer emails but reads them?

Tags: communication, email

How would you deal with a operations manager who does not reply to emails which call for a specific actions. He was heard saying "if they need me they know where to find me".

Comment: see also: [Manager does not respond to my emails](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27413/168)

Answer (score 3):

> *How would you deal with a operations manager who does not reply to emails which call for a specific actions.*

Two scenarios:

- ***If you share the same work slot/ shift***

  - You can go and talk to them (face to face) for any urgent action item, **after** sending the email, if you both are co-located.
  - If the manager is not within the physical reach (not in same wing, same building etc.), you can try reaching them over IM / phone calls.
- ***If you do not share the same work shift***

  Stick to emails, if things are not responded to when they are needed, after a gentle reminder, copy your manager (if the person is not already your manager) and/or their manager to the email.

That said, if this is something that you need done on a very regular basis, I'd suggest, instead of trying to have ad-hoc conversations, if possible, have a brief recurring meeting set up, where you can go over the list of items which needs the inputs / actions from their side and collect the responses.

Whatever you do, do not forget to send emails - they are the documentary proof of the requirement. Send the email and then *follow up* using any means possible / necessary.