# How can I write that I received no reply after sending multiple reminder emails?

Tags: email

Assume:

1. no technical difficulties. The recipient had been replying by email.
2. 2 weeks have passed, with no replies to 3 or more reminder emails.
3. The recipient prefers email, as they can't be easily telephoned.

How can I write something more forceful than 1, but more tactful than 2 or 3?

> 1. I have not heard from you, after weeks of delay and numerous reminders.
> 2. As I've received nothing after multiple reminder emails, my emails feel overlooked and this matter feels ignored.

Afterword: [These](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21981/22656) [posts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/89540/22656) don't help ([What is appropriate email follow-up etiquette after no response?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10203/22656)), as they involve the *first* reminder email after a *first* email.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a solution that doesn't exist. I doubt there are some magic words which will give you a response when you couldn't elicit one from your multiple reminder emails thus far. Is this a hypothetical question? Because [it appears to have been over 30 days now](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2833/how-to-chase-tactfully-someone-who-ignores-your-multiple-reminder-emails). If this is a real problem, you might want to include some specifics, which may provide for a resolution unique to that situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Telephoning is impractical as the recipient can't be easily telephoned, and may live in another time zone.

If the relationship is important, you'll work round practical difficulties. If it's not, don't worry about it and just move on.

> The recipient can't be further appealed or escalated (e.g. a business acquaintance against whom you can't appeal; CEO's office/Executive Relations).

If you can't personally solve a problem, escalate to your manager. They may be able to apply pressure via a different route.

> or (in serious cases) legal action.

I really can't imagine a situation in which legal action for ignored emails would be appropriate before even trying to phone someone.

Comment: regarding your last sentence - what if it is to your telephone provider, because they've cut off your telephone connection (but, strangely, kept your internet on but are ALSO ignoring your emails?). BOOM.

Answer (score 0):

One technique that works for me is to send email asking direct question where the other party would be strongly compelled to answer "No"

For example:

- Have you given up on finishing this project?

This technique is from book Never Split The Difference by Chris Voss.